# Flutter throwing FormatExceptio when trying to read a JSON file

Tags: json, flutter, dart, future, formatexception

I have the following function:

```
  void readJSON(String path) async {
    
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + path;
    print('Trying to read json file from ' + appDocPath);
    
    final Future<String> response = File(appDocPath).readAsString();
    final data = await json.decode(response.toString());
    final coordinates = await (data['elements'] as List).cast<double>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= coordinates.length; ++i){
      print(i);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I am iterating through every JSON line to print it and see what it contains.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
[        ] E/flutter ( 8316): Instance of 'Future<String>'
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

**Output:**

```
[  +81 ms] E/flutter (10493): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): 
[        ] E/flutter (10493): ^
[        ] E/flutter (10493): 
[        ] E/flutter (10493): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:501:7)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:36:10)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): #5      file.readJSON (package:camera_example/file.dart:50:29)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (10493): 
[   +5 ms] E/flutter (10493): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
[        ] E/flutter (10493): #0      file.readJSON (package:camera_example/file.dart:52:36)
[        ] E/flutter (10493): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (10493):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string response = await File(appDocPath).readAsString();
```

You missed await for a future

Comment: `A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<String>` when I do that..

Comment: Make response a string instead of future

Comment: Also consider `readAsStringSync()`

Comment: That's also a good suggestion @RichardHeap

Comment: Can you print the response before json decode and post it here please?

Comment: @KaushikChandru Check the edits..

Comment: This is right when you are doing json decode. Please comment the decode part and print the response from that document as string

Comment: @KaushikChandru how so?

Comment: After you get the response print it's values immediately

Comment: @KaushikChandru. I am going to post another question about this. Although I am populating a list with all of the values to be written, not all values in the list are written to the JSON file. I'll ask the question and link the Question here if that's ok.

Comment: @KaushikChandru https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611051/flutter-throws-a-format-exception-for-maps-written-to-json-file